# For loop to update columns using lag and delete rows on condition gets very slow

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a for-loop function to update multiple columns (time, distance and speed) calculated from values of the current row and previous row, and delete the row whose value from the updated column (speed) exceeds the cutoff value. The sample table has around 500k records, but takes hours to execute and still do not finish. Indexes, work_mem, fillfactor and vacuum full do not make significant changes. Below is the function I come up with.

```
create or replace function speed_cal_cutoff()
returns void as
$body$
declare
   t_curs cursor for 
      select "id", loggerid, datecon, timecon, 
      time_interval, gcs_distance, gcs_geom, 
      interval_seconds, calculated_speed from mytable;
begin
  for t_row in t_curs
    loop

        update mytable
            set time_interval = (concat(datecon|| ' ' ||timecon)::timestamp) - prev_datetime 
            from (select "id", 
                  lag(loggerid) over (partition by loggerid order by datecon, timecon) as prev_loggerid, 
                  lag(concat(datecon|| ' ' ||timecon)::timestamp) over (partition by loggerid order by loggerid, datecon, timecon) as prev_datetime
                  from mytable) as subquery
        where mytable.id = subquery.id 
            and mytable.loggerid = subquery.prev_loggerid
            and mytable.id = t_row.id; 

        update mytable
            set gcs_distance = subquery.gcs_distance
            from (select "id", ST_Distance(gcs_geom::geography, lag(gcs_geom::geography) over (partition by loggerid order by loggerid, datecon, timecon asc)) as gcs_distance, 
                  lag(loggerid) over (partition by loggerid order by datecon, timecon) as prev_loggerid
                  from mytable) as subquery
        where mytable.id = subquery.id
            and mytable.loggerid = subquery.prev_loggerid
            and mytable.id = t_row.id; 

        update mytable
            set interval_seconds = (extract(EPOCH from time_interval))
        where mytable.id = t_row.id; 

        update mytable  
            set calculated_speed = gcs_distance/interval_seconds
        where mytable.id = t_row.id;

        delete from mytable where calculated_speed > 41.6667 
            and mytable.id = t_row.id; 

  end loop;
end
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

How can I optimize the code for better performance?

**UPDATE:**

Combining all UPDATEs into one and then DELETE on table with 10k records reduces the execution time by 2 minutes. Here's the updated code.

```
create or replace function speed_cal_cutoff()
  returns void as
$BODY$
declare
    tc_curs cursor for 
        select "id", loggerid, datecon, timecon, gcs_geom, after_bat_off, first_point from mytable;
begin
  for t_row in tc_curs 
    loop
        case 
            when t_row.after_bat_off = 1 or t_row.first_point = 1
                then  
                    update mytable
                        set time_interval = null, 
                            distance_interval = null,
                            time_interval_seconds = null,
                            calculated_speed = null
                        where mytable.id = t_row.id; 

            else 
                    update mytable
                        set time_interval = (datecon + timecon) - subquery.prev_datetime,
                            distance_interval = subquery.distance_interval,
                            time_interval_seconds = (extract(EPOCH from (datecon + timecon) - subquery.prev_datetime)),
                            calculated_speed = subquery.distance_interval/(extract(EPOCH from (datecon + timecon) - subquery.prev_datetime))
                            from (select "id", 
                                      lag(loggerid) over (partition by loggerid order by datecon, timecon) as prev_loggerid, 
                                      lag(datecon + timecon) over (partition by loggerid order by loggerid, datecon, timecon) as prev_datetime,
                                      ST_Distance(gcs_geom::geography, lag(gcs_geom::geography) over 
                                                  (partition by loggerid order by loggerid, datecon, timecon)) as distance_interval 
                                  from mytable) as subquery
                        where mytable.id = subquery.id 
                            and mytable.loggerid = subquery.prev_loggerid 
                            and mytable.id = t_row.id; 

                    delete from mytable 
                        where calculated_speed > 41.6667 
                        and mytable.id = t_row.id;
        end case; 
    end loop;
end
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

I will turn the columns into arrays and feed them into the function and try using query parallelism, too. Any other ideas of how to boost up the performance?

Comment: Doing things in a loop is rarely a good choice in a relational database. Can't you simply run **one** UPDATE statement that updates all values and then one DELETE statement that removes those that exceed the threshold?

Comment: Something like this: http://dpaste.com/26VD0RF - if you do think you need the loop you can at least combine the four updates into one (per loop iteration)

Comment: Unrelated, but: what data type are `datecon` and `timecon`? In general it would be better store that in a single column of type `timestamp`. But if one is a `date` and the other a `time`, the the expression `(concat(datecon|| ' ' ||timecon)::timestamp)` can be simplified to `datecon + timecon`

Comment: I am detecting for erroneous data points using the speed value. The criteria is that if the speed of any two consecutive data points is more than the cutoff value, the (current) data point should be removed from the dataset. After it is removed, I would have new/different pairs of two consecutive data points, so speed need to be recalculated and check until no two consecutive data points has higher speed than the cutoff. Also, thank you for the reference!

Comment: You can still combine all four UPDATEs into a single one

Comment: I tried your suggestion; combining all UPDATEs into one and then DELETE. Though, it is still very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres doesn't like repeated massive updates in one transactions - mainly if same value is updated more times. The reason is how Postgres implements MVCC architecture. What you can do

a) Try to reduce number of repeated updates by using a arrays. Array is just in memory structure - and if you have Postgres 10 and higher, then array update is cheap.

b) Try to reduce size of transaction. If you can decomposite your transaction to set of smaller transactions, then is possibility to effective cleaning table heap, and there is a change for significantly faster execution.

```
# bad technique, pseudocode
begin;
for i in 1 .. 100 loop
  for j in 1 .. 1000 loop -- any value will be updated 100x without cleaning
    update tab set v = j + i where pk = j;
  end loop;
end loop;
commit;

# better
for i in 1 .. 100 loop
  begin;
  for j in 1 .. 1000 loop -- any value will be updated 100x without cleaning
    update tab set v = j + i where pk = j;
  end loop;
  commit;
end loop;
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! After deleting the row whose speed exceeds the cutoff value, the table size will become smaller. So, I do not think I shall put in exact loop range like `for i in .. 100 loop` or `for j in 1 .. 1000 loop`?

Comment: I am not sure if the loop is needed at all - would the outer cursor "see" the DELETEs done in the loop? If not, then I think the loop can be removed completely

Comment: @Beau - it was just example. What is important is length of transactions. If you do massive updates of same values, then you write code that has shorted transactions. If you use a arrays, then it is not necessary. Just load data to array, do calculations, and save data from array to table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I believe it sees as LAGs pull values correctly even after rows are deleted.